# Write a method that returns the sum of numbers divisible by a divisor in a given range (range includes from / to)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, methods

> ```
> public static int sumDivisible(int from, int to, int divisor){}
> ```
>
> Example: divisor: 2, from: 2, to: 6 Result: 12 (2+4+6)

I can't understand how to build it. Someone please explain.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Example: divisor: 2, from: 2, to: 6");
      int from = 2;
       int to = 6;
       int div = 2;
       for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
      { if (i % div == 0) { System.out.println("Result: " + sum(from, div, to, i)); } }
           }
           public static int sum (int from, int div, int to, int i)
           { return i; }
        }
```

This is something that I tried.

Comment: Define a variable to hold the result, perhaps `int sum = 0;` and add every matching number to it, then return it at the end `return sum;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile. First you need to define a method as shown in your question.

```
public static int sumDivisible(int from, int to, int divisor){}
```

Between the {} you need to.

- initialize a value (sum) to 0.
- then, using a for loop, iterate from `from` to `to`, and incrementing by `1`
- if the loop value is divisible by `divisor`, then add it to sum.
- when the loop is done, return the sum.

You seem to have some problems understanding basic Java syntax.  I recommend you discuss this with your instructor.